# Java : How to achieve socket programming functionality with 3rd party API

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I am working on a Existing Java Application, which is using Java Socket Programming for connecting to servers.
Now my task is to replace this Socket Programming with a Third Party API.

To get the Data from the server with Socket Programming we can simply use:

```
InputStream socketInput = socket.getInputStream();
```

The above line will take care of getting the Data from the servers.

But how can we implement this behavior without using any Socket Programming?

Any ideas as how to implement this?

Comment: What data are you retrieving from the servers? Data from a database? Your best bet would probably be to replace the socket with a webserver/web service.

Comment: Correct , after connecting to their servers we are getting some Database data

Comment: Sounds like you're going to need to write yourself some sort of webservice

Comment: cant we have create an byte array , read this Database data  and convert it to stream and set it in inputstream

Comment: Thank you very much , any other alternate solution rather than using webServices

Comment: Using sockets is normal Java programming.

Comment: Are you asking for a 3rd party solution or do you have a 3rd party API in mind.  If the latter then please post details about it.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what the third party toolkit was or what approach or protocol it was using. You can't avoid using sockets on some level when doing network programming, but you can use Java's higher level network APIs like HTTPUrlConnection to do HTTP operations for sending and receiving data.

Comment: i have a question here , cant we have create an byte array and convert it to stream and set it in inputstream

Answer (score 0):

If the third party API is also using stream abstraction it is simple. You just have to get input/output streams from other source.

If this API uses higher level abstraction (e.g. works directly with objects of your data model) you need to replace that layer in your code.

Please try to ask more specific question and you will get more specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want use your own protocol but without using java.net directly you could use event-driven frameworks such as :

- [Apache Mina](http://mina.apache.org/)
- [JBoss Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty)

But if your considering sending your data over other protocols check this question [Is there a good Java networking library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414020/is-there-a-good-java-networking-library)